# Shaded error bar matlab

Tags: matlab

I've imported 3 vectors (500x1 double) from excel that I wanna plot, but my code doesn't work.

```
x=frequency;
y=real_part;
    figure;hold on;

    H(1) = shadedErrorBar(x, y, {@mean, @(x) 0.25*std(x)  }, '-r', 0);
```

where frequency and real_part are 2 of my 3 vectors.
It says

> Error using shadedErrorBar (line 85) length(x) must equal
>   length(errBar)
>
> Error in Untitled2 (line 5) H(1) = shadedErrorBar(x, y, {@mean, @(x)
>   2*std(x)  }, '-r', 0);

but all of them have the same lenght. Can you help me?
I took here the code http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/08/17/shaded-error-bars/

Comment: If both `x` and `y` are 500x1 how can you have a variance of `y` for each `x`? The code you use calculates the error bar by calculating the variance.

Comment: x is the frequency (500 values); y is the mean for each frequency. What is the problem?

Comment: that you should have repeated values of y for each x. In the example is 15: `y=ones(15,1)*x;`. so that the amplitude of the error bar at each `x` is determined by the std of the 15 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x is **500x1 double**, as you said. But both of the anonymous functions (`@mean, @(x) 0.25*std(x)`) give you **1x1 double** when they apply on x. This is why you get an error on size mismatch.

I think you are missing a point here. If you have the error values in the third vector you mentioned - let's call it `error_bars` - then this should work:

```
shadedErrorBar(x , y , error_bars , '-r' , 0);
```

I am quoting from [shadedErrorBar on File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26311-shadederrorbar):

---

- x - vector of x values
- y - vector of y values or a matrix of n observations by m cases
    where m has length(x);
- errBar - if a vector we draw symmetric errorbars. If it has a
         size of [2,length(x)] then we draw asymmetric error bars
         with row 1 being the upper bar and row 2 being the lower
         bar. ** alternatively ** errBar can be a cellArray of
         two function handles. The first defines which statistic
         the line should be and the second defines the error
         bar.

---